# Live migration: is it possible to store image disks on a single iscsi target?

Tags: iscsi, libvirt, open-iscsi

From redhat documentation:

```
A guest virtual machine installed on shared storage using one of the following protocols:
 Fibre Channel-based LUNs
 iSCSI
 FCoE
 NFS
SCSI RDMA protocols (SCSI RCP): the block export protocol used in Infiniband and 
10GbE iWARP adapters
```

Till now I simply created an iscsi target leading to a .dsk file which was the VM's hard disk.
Problem is that now I'd like to have a central server hosting .dsk files so that, installing a custom program on it, I could generate new vms by simply copying these .dsk files.

In short: I'd like to implement an on demand VM creation, generating their hard disks by simply copying files.

So, my idea would be to set the VM's disk to

```
<source file='<network file system root path/aVMImage.dsk'/>
```

Is it possible to do something like that? And would live migration still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your central storage server export the directory of disk images over NFS. The servers running the VMs can access the disk images using the [Network Filesystem](http://libvirt.org/storage.html#StorageBackendNetFS) backend for libvirt storage pools, or you can perform the NFS mount yourself and use the [directory](http://libvirt.org/storage.html#StorageBackendDir) backend.  Migration should work.

Comment: I will try and let you know, it seems a good idea!  Have you any easy to set up nfs server implementation for linux to suggest to me? (i am using ubuntu)

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html

Comment: It seems it requires a subnet...but this storage should be accessed by anyone throught the internet. I'll add some sort of authentication (saw it supports kerberos and ldap), but I don't want to put a limitation on the ips who can access to my nfs...

Comment: "this storage should be accessed by anyone throught the internet". That sounds unusual and dangerous. Why shouldn't the IPs should be limited to your virtualization hosts?

Comment: Because my hypervisors are not on the same local network. If an hypervisor wants to associate a disk image, present on my image storage server, to his vm he has to be allowed to do so.

Comment: Even though they're not on the local network you still know the IP addresses of your hypervisors, right?

Comment: yes but as it is for a thesis project I don't have any registered IP address so they just change according to my ISP...oh well * wildcard will do, your answer is correct :)